# Cannot see boot message to choose which OS (Windows or Ubuntu)

Tags: installation, dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu using USB drive. I installed it along side Windows 7.

But I have a problem. I cannot see which OS (Windows or Ubuntu) I should enter after booting my laptop. It normally boots Windows 7 but still I can load Ubuntu after connecting my USB.

Please some one tell me what I should do. I'm not much familiar with computers. Please give me full instructions to do this.

I typed it in terminal and it shows

```
samith@samith-Inspiron-N5050:~$ grub-install /dev/sda2
rm: cannot remove `/boot/grub/915resolution.mod': Permission denied
samith@samith-Inspiron-N5050:~$
```

Can I restart laptop now?

Comment: What is the output of sudo fdisk -l?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have Grub on the USB flash drive, and it has to be moved to the install grub to your hard drive.  To do that, with the USB plugged in, boot into Ubuntu just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdaX (where X is your primary disk )
```

if you get any errors, try

```
sudo grub-install --force /dev/sda2
```

To find out which one is your primary disk,(in the image below, it would be sda1) just type

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

[image]

When done,  do `sudo update-grub`, remove the USB, and restart your system.

Try to re-install grub2 to the mbr from the live cd. This site would help: http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Comment: Is that star shown one???.....my dev/sda2 shows (*)

Comment: Normally yes, but just to be safe, can you upload an image somewhere, give me the URL, and I'll post it for you.

Comment: samith@samith-Inspiron-N5050:~$ grub-install /dev/sda2
rm: cannot remove `/boot/grub/915resolution.mod': Permission denied
samith@samith-Inspiron-N5050:~$ 

Is that correct??? Can I restart my laptop now??????

Comment: it shows.......samith@samith-Inspiron-N5050:~$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda2
[sudo] password for samith: 
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: Attempting to install GRUB to a partitionless disk or to a partition.  This is a BAD idea..
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
samith@samith-Inspiron-N5050:~$

Comment: will it harmful to my laptop?????....plz????

Comment: installing grub shouldn't.  Let me know the outcome.

Comment: this is it.......samith@samith-Inspiron-N5050:~$ sudo grub-install --force /dev/sda2
[sudo] password for samith: 
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: Attempting to install GRUB to a partitionless disk or to a partition.  This is a BAD idea..
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
Installation finished. No error reported.
samith@samith-Inspiron-N5050:~$ 


Can I restart again now??

Comment: oh..noooooooooooooooo..........now it appears which one to choose....but my windows not loading now!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: it appears.................ubuntu 12.04 generic /ubuntu 12.4 generic(recovery mode) /lynux...(I can not remember) & finally windows loader........I clicked windows loader but not load windows!!!!!!!!.........What should i do now...........

Comment: HOW????????? I do not know how re install grub2...plz tell me..

Comment: sorry......I do not want to upgrade it.I already have grub 1.99-ubuntu3.1.......so what I should do????

Comment: so..what did u mention by "sudo update-grub" earlier ????...should I type it in termial????? and then??

Comment: Please make sure you are both updating your posts to reflect new data. @user83149 Yes you type that in your terminal.

Comment: I typed it...but not solve problem..still I can not load windows...please give me full instructions to solve this....I red that" http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2" article...but I can not understand...please..I don't know what I should do..